# error: class has no constructor caused by using abstractController symfony4.2?

Tags: symfony-4.2

please can u tell me what how to use AbstractController in symfony4.2 and how to inject services in contruct Controller?

```
nameSpace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class homeController extends AbstractController
{    
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/home", name="home")
     */


    public function index():Response
    {
        return $this->render('pages/home.html.twig');
    }

}
```

how to inject services in controller's constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify required service as Controller constructor argument. And then assign service to your controller parameter.
For example:

```
public function construct(StringValidator $stringValidator) 
{
    $this->stringValidator = $stringValidator;
}
```

Dont forget to declare $stringValidator in your parameters and also specify required Service namespace! In case of enabled `autowiring` in your `services.yaml` you dont even need to pass Service argument manually.
That's all. You can use your service now.